# Duty exemption for non-resident aliens

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, import-taxes

I would like to bring food (i.e. milk chocolate, cookies, ...) back from my home country (France) into the US. I don't go home often, so I'd like to bring back about $200 worth of food items. I am currently a PhD student holding an F1 visa.

As the Customs and Border protection puts it:

> Whether or not you are eligible for an exemption and what it will be depends on 
>   your residency status, the country you are coming from, how long you were 
>   there, what you purchased or received, the country the goods were made in, and 
>   the price paid for the goods. [source](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/454/~/duty-free-exemption%2C-gifts)

There seems to be general rules for US citizens, however:

> **Exemptions**
>   Depending on the countries you have visited, your personal exemption will be 
>   $200, $800, or $1,600. [source](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/246/~/duty--free-exemption)

I cannot find similar guidelines for non-resident aliens, however. I did find this:

> If you are a nonresident visiting the U.S. with gifts, your personal 
>   belongings, or goods for resale, there is a possibility you will not have to 
>   pay duty. For instance, if you are visiting the U.S. for 72 hours or more you 
>   are allowed to bring up to $100 worth of goods duty-free. [source](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/454/~/duty-free-exemption%2C-gifts)

I am not sure, however, whether this depends on anything like one's visa status, or the length of one's stay beyond 72 hours, and so on.

**How much can I bring back duty-free from my home country as an F1-visa holder (PhD student)?**

Comment: This is better fit for [Expats.SE](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Have you been in the US more than 5 years? If so, you're considered a resident for tax purposes and possibly also for the customs/duty exemption.

Comment: @mkennedy: I've been in the US for 6 months

Comment: @vartec: This is a non-immigrant visa, so I'm not sure how relevant expats.se would be.

Comment: I think you will mostly have issues with importing food. The USA is not very fond of food imports because of possible diseases and for protectionist reasons. Regarding the eligibility of expats.SE, it should be OK as it lists 1 year+ residence visas (which is your case).

Comment: https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/975/~/visitors-gift-exemptions

This clearly explains that the visitor exemption is only $100, there is no mention of the class of goods that can be imported and it clearly says that anything above would be charged a 3% duty rate, if you dont mind paying $3, then it should be fine, I dont have an authoritative response, but the link seems fairly clear

Comment: https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/82/kw/chocolates does say you are fine bringing chocolates

Comment: The word "citizen" is nowhere mentioned in the second source that you cited.

Comment: @200_success: True. For some reason I assumed that it applied to US citizens, given that the other source mentioned foreigners specifically.

Comment: @skv: Sure. I was just looking for a bit more of information; possibly more detailed (in particular since, as 200_success points out, there is no mention in the other source of the other limits applying only to US citizens)

Comment: @Clément: all visas, except *EB-* types, which directly grant green card, are *"non-immigrant visas"*. Including dual intent ones such as for example *H1*. Anyways, staying for few semesters is out of scope of this site (it's not traveling) and within the scope of Expats site.